# Spring Boot 3 with Spring Batch 5: @SpringBatchTest Fails to Read Properties and Initialize Schema in H2 DB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-test

I recently updated a new Spring Batch project I'm writing to version 3 of Spring Boot and version 5 of Spring Batch. I have upgraded these dependencies to fix vulnerabilities that cause my CI/CD pipeline to reject my build. Anyway, I have a Spring Batch Test that ran just fine before the upgrade that is now failing with an exception. The first problem I ran into was that Spring could no longer resolve placeholders. Oh! And yes, I am running on Java 17.

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'aws.secrets.secret-region' in value "${aws.secrets.secret-region}"`

The properties are defined in:
`src/test/resources/application.yml`

```
aws:
    secrets:
        secret-id: some/secretId
        secret-region: some-aws-region
```

The only thing I got to work, as far as the properties go, is to define each one like so:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
"aws.secrets.secret-region=some-aws-region",
"aws.secrets.secret-id=some/secretId",
"spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE",
"spring.batch.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE", 
... Other properties removed for brevity... })
```

This isn't the best solution because it is redundant. I shouldn't have to redefine properties that are in the `application.yml` file. Now, while this does work, this leads to my next problem. When I run the tests again, I get a new exception:

`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ACCOUNT" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:`

The ACCOUNT table should exist in the H2 database. One, it works in similar tests even after the upgrade. Two, it worked in this test before the upgrade. My test is annotated as follows:

```
@SpringBatchTest 
@EnableAutoConfiguration 
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AccountJobConfig.class, other dependencies removed for brevity...})
```

As stated above, I tried adding `@TestPropertySource` expecting it to resolve my `application.yml` issue. But, pointing it to the actual properties file did nothing (`@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yml")`). I tried adding `@SpringBootTest` to the test class and it caused DB tables to not be found. So, `@SpringBootTest` resolves the property issue. But, it isn't required on my other, similar, tests. FYI, my other tests use `@DataJpaTest` alongside `@SpringBatchTest`. But when I add `@DataJpaTest` to this test class, my tables still aren't found. I have tried searching Google and StackOverflow for a solution, but haven't been able to find anything that has worked. I've even tried chatting with ChatGPT. Its knowledge isn't up-to-date enough for Spring Boot 3 and Spring Batch 5. I had a coworker look at this issue for a couple of hours. He suggested I post it here on StackOverflow.

I tried removing `@EnableBatchProcessing` from `AccountJobConfig`, but that leads to the following exception:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry' available:`

You are probably wondering what this failing test does that the other passing tests don't. Well, because I use a `JpaCursorItemReader` and a `JpaItemWriter` in my batch job, I need to load the test H2 DB with data to process. I have a `@BeforeEach` method that does this. It calls the 'account' JPA repository and tries to save a newly created account entity. The test fails in the 'before' method when trying to perform an insert statement.